# What is the significant difference between a Rogue Access Point & Client Mis-Association

Tags: wifi, wireless, forensics

As the title states, how can I differentiate both of them.

Answer (score 2):

Client Misassociation just describes that the client will automatically connect to the device since it assumes that it is a previously trusted one, i.e. same SSID and maybe same MAC too. Rogue AP just means that the AP is malicious.

These two terms describe different aspects: It might be possible that the device connects automatically to a rogue AP due to client misassociation. But a user might also explicitly connect to the rogue AP since it believes that it is fine (i.e. trust sounding name like "Free City WiFi"), i.e. without client misassociation. And misassociation might also happen because of conflicting configurations and the AP does not actually need to be rogue.

Comment: Agree with the comment, based in tutorialspoint Client Misassociation  -  If the signal from that AP, would be better than the one from original AP, the laptop software will mis-associate to the fake (rogue) access point provided by the hacker (thinking it is the legitimate AP, you have used in the past).

Comment: In corporate networks, a “rogue access point” may refer to an access point not run and not authorized by the IT organization.  If plugged into the corporate network, this can pose a security and compliance risk.  The installer may not intend for it to “malicious”, but it’s deployment is in violation of company policy.

Comment: The MAC isn't taken into account, if you have stored an ESSID on a device there may be multiple access points (All with different MAC address) and your device would just "roam" through the one with the strongest signal.